# Proving that a finite point set is closed by using limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In a metric space $X$, or just $R^K$, $E \subset X$ is a closed set if every limit point of $E$ is a point of $E$. Is it possible to use only this fact, or definition, to prove that a finite point set is closed?

I know we can prove that because the complement of a finite point set is open. However, since a finite point set has no limit points as every neighborhood of a limit point should contain infinitely many points of $E$, I cannot figure out how to use this concept of limit points to prove that a finite point set is closed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $E$ has no limit points, then all of them are vacuously elements of $E.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a closed set (in a metric space) is a set which contains all of its limit points (note that this is only one of many commonly use equivalent definitions).
Since a finite set has no limit points (proved below), we can conclude that it contains all of its limit points (since there are none).

Therefore, **any finite subset of a metric space is closed**.

> **Proposition**: If a set $X$ in a metric space has a limit point $x$, then $X$ is infinite.

*Proof*.
Consider the ball of radius $r=1$ centred at $x$.
By our assumption, this ball contains a point in $X$ that is distinct from $x$. 
Call this point $x_{1}$.
Now, consider the ball of radius $r=d(x,x_{1})$ centred at $x$.
Again, this ball contains a point in $X$ that is distinct from $x$.
Moreover, this new point cannot equal to $x_{1}$ due to our choice of radius.
Call this new point $x_{2}$.
Continuing this way, we obtain a sequence of points in $X$ which are all distinct from each other.
Therefore, $X$ is infinite.

Comment: I don't get the meaning of being "trivially" closed. Does that mean that because a finite point set is not open, it is closed...?

Comment: Trivially just means "easily". I added more detail.